# Delegate problem when calling function from EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use the timer class in C# for this TCM Updater and I keep getting an error: "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."

I thought I would just have to add "this" to the beginning of the function, but still getting that error. Any idea what I might need to do?

this is the code I am using (error on function call 5 lines down):

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  updateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
  updateTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.onUpdateEvent);   <--- Error here
  updateTimer.Interval = 2000;
  updateTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnUpdateEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

Comment: Is the mis-match in case between the method and the call in the constructor a typo or is that how it is in your code?

Comment: The code works for me on a 3.5 winforms form. No error. There's a typo in your code. Small o in error line and capital O for method signature. Just making sure that isn't significant.

Comment: how is updateTimer defined? not static or something?

Comment: @pfunc: it does look like you have a typo, which is causing the error.  For future note when you have an error, it's best to cut-and-paste the error message into the question, it would give us a hint really fast instead of us guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this: `updateTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.onUpdateEvent);`

To this:  `updateTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnUpdateEvent);`

Or the simplified syntax (as others have suggested): `updateTimer.Elapsed += OnUpdateEvent;`

Comment: oh sheesh, thanks... this is what I get for programming with little sleep.

Answer (score 1):

aside from the typo: why not just write

```
updateTimer.Elapsed += OnUpdateEvent;
```

Comment: No, if you think what usually happens in InitializeComponent, ie wiring up all the controls with their handlers, that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: sorry you are right - but please note that 'this' in the constructor is a tricky thing ;)

Comment: I think the this is a bit of a red herring. I think the error relates (according to google) to something internal to a delegate. All good fun :)

Answer (score 0):

try this if this works for you!

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = newSystem.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 2000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a very simple solution is to make the method OnUpdateEvent static, if you don't need any instance members.